# how to write routes.php file in controllar using codeigniter?

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

I using codeigniter to trying add text in routes.php , What I want to do is add text in config/routes.php,  I had update the route.php file to 777 permission, but it was not working.

here is my code

```
$file_path = "var/www/html/staging/oscar/anthola/application/config/routes.php";
$file_exists = read_file($file_path);
$slug ="123";
if ( ! write_file($file_path, $slug))
{
     echo 'Unable to write the file';
    echo write_file('./config/routes.php', $slug);
}
else
{
     echo 'File written!';
      echo write_file('./config/routes.php', $slug);
}
```

Any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: Are you sure you want this solution? I'd suggest you to reconsider and instead use the `$route['404_override'] = '';` and run this through a controller. The controller can then make decisions based on `uri` library and database values. Avoid modifying dynamicly php-files, even more one such as `route.php` since a little generated missplaced sign will shut down your entire website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Robin's comments, but if this is the route you want to go down then I would recommend adding the following line towards the bottom of your routes.php file:

```
include_once APPPATH . "cache/routes.php";
```

This way, you won't be overwriting the `default_controller` and `404_override` routes, but will still be able to add additional routes to your Codeigniter application.

In your controller, you can then just add the following couple of lines

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$output = '$route["route"] = "controller/action";';
write_file(APPPATH . "cache/routes.php", $output);
```

Hope that helps.